# Emailling through DNS server

Tags: c#, smtp

I have an c# automated email program, however I have been told by our tech team our server has no access to DNS servers at any time and that I need to provide them with one to relay its SMTP setup, to send an email.

Can I just use and give them an open DNS server? Is it the same thing? I don't understand what the need for a DNS server is, are they trying to setup a smart host?

Comment: Probably should be moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is somewhat unclear, but it sounds as though they're saying that the SMTP client component of your application has to do a DNS lookup to find its SMTP server by hostname. And the question is: where is the DNS server that will supply this lookup?

So I think you want to give them the IP address of a stable DNS server that can translate the hostname of the SMTP server for you.